# In kivy2 or kivymd, is there a way to create a screen dynamically without adding them to a kv file

Tags: python, kivy, screen, kivymd

for example... lets say i have alot of products.

i want to be able to have the program know a certain products was clicked... easy enough

but then i want the program to create a screen based off of a template

basically on the fly.

thanks for the help

this is what i have tried so far.

```
def Create_New_Product_Screen(self,question,Screen_Name):
    print(self,Screen_Name+'Made it here')
    sm = ScreenManager()
    screen = Screen(name=Screen_Name)
    sm.add_widget(screen)
    #sm.current = Screen_Name
    app = MDApp.get_running_app()
    app.change_screen(Screen_Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Create_New_Screen(self,Screen_Name):
    app = MDApp.get_running_app()
    sm = app.root.ids['screen_manager']
    screen = Screen(name=Screen_Name)
    sm.add_widget(screen)
    sm.current = Screen_Name
```

Now i just need to figure out how to make templates for the screens
but this worked... i had to find the screen manager in the kivy file
and then call it and create the screen then change to it.